# Currency formatting in a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency, nsnumberformatter

I was wondering if anyone is able to clear this up for me.

I'm creating a test app with two buttons, adding 10% or 20% to a value input by the user. It was working fine until I tried to format it to currency. The research I've done so far told me I shouldn't be using floats but I'm not too sure what to use in their place.

```
    float a = ([entryAmount.text floatValue]);
    float v = (10 * a / 100);
    float y = (20 * a / 100);

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *currencyString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:a]];
    entryAmount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currencyString];

    float z = (a + y);
    answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Adding 20% brings it too %.2f",z];
```

Once tapping outside the text field, it does reformat the input value and even makes the calculation, but then if I tap another button it resets the text field back to 0. I'm aware that the answer will not currently display in the currency format, I'm trying to make it so that the text field automatically formats after user input, and if another option is pressed then it simply doesn't reset the field.

Comment: You should use NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber instead of float for currency. But I don't see a reason why it is reset after touching another button. It doesn't look like a problem with float, your code should have screwed somewhere else.

Comment: Side note - do not use `stringWithFormat` just to assign a string. Simply do: `entryAmount.text = currencyString`.

Comment: Side note 2 - To calculate 10% you can simply do: `float v = a * 0.1;` and for 20% do: `float y = a * 0.2;`.